# How can I interrogate an SqlDataReader object for containing data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am logging in using a username and password and this is my code in DAL

```
public static SqlDataReader login(SchoolBAL bal)
 {
  SqlConnection con = DBConnection.OpenConnection();
  try
   {
   int i;
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("login", con);
   cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", bal.UserName);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", bal.Password);
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
   return dr;
   }catch (Exception)
    {
      throw;
    }
 }
```

but i want to return an integer here how can i do it?

EDIT::

```
    Create procedure login
(@username varchar (50),@password varchar (50))

as
begin
select UserName,password from tblLogin where UserName=@username and password=@password
end
```

Comment: but what to have to do ?

Comment: what do you mean "use int and return it"?

Comment: But what represents the int returned? The user presence in the database (0/1) ?

Comment: Please include `stored-procedure` code in your post.

Comment: @downvoters may i know the reason?? it would be helpful for me and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the reference of `DataReader` but return type of method is `int`. Change the return type of method.

```
public static bool login(SchoolBAL bal)
{
  bool isFound=false;
  using(SqlConnection con = DBConnection.OpenConnection())
   {
    using(SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("login", con))
    {
     cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", bal.UserName);
     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", bal.Password);
     con.Open(); 
     SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
     if(dr.Read())
       isFound=true;
     dr.Close();
     con.Close();
     }
    }
  return isFound;
}
```

Comment: ya i know but i want to return an integer here how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the `int` from your sproc then use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - and return that value.

But you should maybe think about this design, what does that value mean to anybody?

Maybe use an `Enum` or even true/false.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int login(SchoolBAL bal)
   {
       SqlConnection con = DBConnection.OpenConnection();
       try
       {
           int i;
           SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("login", con);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", bal.UserName);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", bal.Password);
           i = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
           return i;              

       }
       catch (Exception)
       {

           throw;
       }
   }
```

Comment: it should be ExecuteScalar, not executeScaler. I have corrected that.